# How do I convert a string to HTML won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

tWhat is wrong with this code? Originally I had the element of an array render. But it was just diplaying as a string not as HTML as it should so I tried to convert using code from,

https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/84/string-to-html-in-react-js

the second type, Using HTML-react-parser npm package. But unfortunately I'm getting

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

    [eslint] 
    src/App.js
  Line 4:36:   'string' is not defined                   no-undef
  Line 9:1:    Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 10:1:   Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 11:1:   Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 23:5:   'arrs_list' is not defined                no-undef
  Line 32:11:  'html' is not defined                     no-undef
```

Here is part of the App.js file.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
export const StringToHtml = () =>{
  const [html, setHtml] = useState<string>("")
  useEffect(() => {
    setHtml("<div>Html stored as a string</div>")
  }, [html])
}
function App() {
    const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
    const word = 1;
        const [arrs_list,setarrs]=useState(['<input type="text"/>'])
  return (
      <div className="App">
 ...
         <br></br>
          {arrs_list.map( (arr,index)=>
              (
              <p key={index}>{arr}</p>
              )   
          )}

         <>
          {parse(html)}
          </>
          <div></div>
          </div>
    
          );
           }
    export default App;
```

As the site suggests I installed html-react-parser in the terminal.

Comment: You should use the .tsx suffix as the code contains TypeScript code. App.tsx

Comment: Your code is so messed up. First of all, I don't think you actually want to parse the HTML. You can just [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html) it. Also, unless a function is a React component or a hook, you can't use other hooks within (`StringToHtml` is neither a component or a hook, but you're using `useState`).

Comment: yeah, that's not javascript, which is your first problem.

Comment: "What is wrong with this code?" - I don't want to be mean about this but mostly everything. 1) Why are you trying to render HTML stored in state? 2) What is `StringToHtml` meant to be? It's not a function _or_ a component. Even if it _was_ a component the useEffect would cause an infinite loop.  3) What is the `val` state meant to be doing? I really suggest you go and read the [introductory documenation for React](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn) if you haven't already as it's not clear that you understand what it is or how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
<div style={{display: 'contents'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}></div>
```